# Selenium WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' while calling sendkeys method

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When trying to call Sendkeys method in selenium webdriver it is displaying below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'  
 (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)  
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Selenium Jarversion: 3.10.0

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Answer (score 13):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64)
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.27*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.27*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v54-56**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.10.0*.
- Your *JDK version* is *unknown* to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.27*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [**ChromeDriver v2.36**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.36 release notes](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: In what sense does the error "say it all"? It's true that it prints out a version of chrome and a version of chrome driver, but doesn't really make any indication that a version mismatch is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

An older version of the ChromeDriver is being spun off when the test is being run; to remedy:

- Ensure that you've gotten your browser up to date (v65-67) and get the latest version of the ChromeDriver executable(v2.38)
- Extract the ChromeDriver and explicitly set the System property when initializing the ChromeDriver object...

Ex:

1. `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");`
2. `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same issue. The issue got resolved by updating the chromedriverexe. please check the compatibility of your chrome browser with chrome driver here [To download chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)