# How to open multiple webpages in separate tabs within a browser using selenium-webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs, webdriver

I want to open mulitple local htmls within same browser window using Selenium Webdriver using Python. I have tried following in Jupyter notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver

1page = "file://<path for 1.html>"
2page = "file://<path for 2.html>"
firefox_path = 'C:\geckodriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= firefox_path)
driver.get(1page)
# For opening 2nd HTML in another Tab
driver.execute_script('''window.open('''+ 2page + ''',"_blank");''')
```

Running above code lead me to the following error:

```
JavascriptException: Message: Error: Access to 'file://<path of 2.html>' from script denied
```

How to mitigate this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open multiple *URLs* / *webpages* in seperate *TABs* within a browser you can use the following solution :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  first_page = "http://www.google.com"
  second_page = "https://www.facebook.com/" 
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(first_page)
  driver.execute_script("window.open('" + second_page +"');")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot :

[image: multiple_tabs]

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. But, how about local html pages?

Comment: `get()` method accepts _URL_ as `String`. So you can use `get()` through passing `local html pages` just like the way we have passed `first_page` and `second_page` as variables to `get()`

Comment: Are you seeing any difference in the solution apart from what I commented? Where are you exactly stuck? Are you seeing any error? Update the question with your _code trial_ and error stack trace please.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested. It opens the said tabs in new window instead of current window. Also it shows me `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)`

Comment: @abhi1610 The error `call function result missing 'value'` is a common error stemming out of **incompatible version** of the binaries you are using and have no relation with this question/answer. Follow the discussion [Selenium WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' while calling sendkeys method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219594/selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value/49219750#49219750) to solve it.