# When scraping using selenium, url opens in new window. it should be in the new tab

Tags: python, selenium

When I scrape the URL, it directs to the log in page. After logging in, it opens to  new window  and what is worst, it returns system error.

Comment: Did you try testing manually too? and what's the result?
Please provide your code  and the website link here to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the url getting opened within a [*new window*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522779/how-to-open-multiple-webpages-in-separate-tabs-within-a-browser-using-selenium-w/50523219#50523219) or within a [new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs/53692407#53692407), all you need is to switch through the [*window_handles*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961842/is-there-any-way-to-get-all-tab-titles-of-browser-without-switching) to access them one after another.