# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm automating a web app in chrome browser in Android Mobile. I've ADV with version 7.0

I'm trying to send user name for login using below code -

```
driver = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://site-url/");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("myemailid@gmail.com")
```

It throws below exception -

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: call function result missing 'value'   (Session info:
>   chrome=71.0.3578.99)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
>   (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

**Note:** please don't mark it as duplicate. solution from below references are not working for me.

1. [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609069/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-call-function-result-miss)
2. [Selenium WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' while calling sendkeys method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219594/selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value/49219750)

I'm using latest chrome version i.e. 71 and chromedriver 2.45 . It doesn't seems a compatibility issue.

**Observation :**  chromedriver version 2.45 used to set property but it shows `chromedriver=2.33.506120` in exception

Comment: Can you check whether port is referring the different server or the URL is proper?

Comment: every thing is fine. the issue is with `sendkeys` i'm able to perform click on buttons and links

Comment: check the email field whether it can be enabled on click. Because human action clicks then send the keys. Automation just sends the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems default Appium's `chromedriver.exe` issue in my case as it was taking `chromedriver=2.33.506120` by default even i have set 2.45 version. following workaround resolved my issue.

**Prerequisites** 
Should have compatible `chromedriver.exe` version with the chrome version installed in device/emulator

> setting chromedriver.exe path in Appium using
>   `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
>   "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver.exe");` won't work

**Use following ways to set chromedriver path in Appium:**

1. Using `DesiredCapabilities` e.g.

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554 (9)");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
   capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
   capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
   capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "D:\\chromedriver_win32_2.45\\chromedriver.exe");
   ```
2. Provide chromedriver.exe path while start Appium Server. Refer below snap

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to make it comment but to make it clear I write it here. Yes it duplicate above post, see the log

> (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.99)
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120

You are using chromedriver `2.33` that for Chrome  `v60-62` then

> I'm using latest chrome version i.e. 61 and chromedriver 2.45 . It
>   doesn't seems a compatibility issue.

ChromeDriver `2.45` is for Chrome `v70-72`

solution: see [download page](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for other compatibility and download

Comment: Hey. I don't know from where it is taking `chromedriver=2.33.506120` . I have downloaded 2.45 and configured the path in `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: outside folder where chromedriver 2.45 located, try  run `where chromedriver` in CMD

Comment: its Powershell command, then try this `D:\Eclipse\chromedriver.exe --version` and also try replace double `\\` with `/`

Comment: last try :D print the property `System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));`

Comment: it display the same path what i set.